# .NET EntityStoreSchemaFilterEntry filter patterns

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, edmx, edmgen

First question to SO, I hope I'm doing this right. ;)

Regarding System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityStoreSchemaFilterEntry :

I'm looking for some detailed documentation on this class. The MSDN docs have nothing but an indication of what properties exist and their data types. I want to create a well-defined list of filters for

```
EntityStoreSchemaGenerator.GenerateStoreMetadata(
   IEnumerable<EntityStoreSchemaFilterEntry> filters
)
```

Specifically:

- Do we need to set all Excludes before the Allows so that Allow entries are the only ones that are returned?

  What are the consequences of using null in any of the parameters? What about empty string "" ? Comments about this seem to be conflicting and don't match my experience with their usage.

  Is the proper "all" wildcard a simple "%"?

My goal is to Exclude all Tables, Views, and Filters, then Allow just the ones that I want. If I try to do this I get an edmx file with no entities. It seems my Exclude All takes precedence over all of the tables that I tried to include. If I don't try to exclude tables that I don't want, I get the tables I've Allowed plus all other tables in the database, which sort of renders filtering useless.

For reference, the only info I can find about proper wildcard patterns for filters is here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms710171(VS.85).aspx

Note that I've gone way beyond EdmGen, noted bugs and limitations in EdmGen2, and am now trying to accomplish what I need with a **majorly** extended EdmGen2 base.

Thanks!

*Related keywords to assist people searching on this topic:*

```
AEF ADO.NET Entity Framework
Tables Views Functions
EntityStoreSchemaFilterObjectTypes EntityStoreSchemaFilterEffect
EntityStoreSchemaGenerator GenerateStoreMetadata
EntityModelSchemaGenerator
SSDL CSDL MSL EDMX
EdmGen EdmGen2
```

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I also have an updated version of the EdmGen2 code base and am looking for ways to limit the tables used by ModelGens call to GenerateStoreMetadata.

Answer (score 1):

I found the follow filters were sufficient to generate the SSDL for a single table.

```
List<EntityStoreSchemaFilterEntry> filters = new List<EntityStoreSchemaFilterEntry>();
// Just generate for the Document table.
filters.Add(new EntityStoreSchemaFilterEntry(null, "dbo", "TargetTableNameHere", EntityStoreSchemaFilterObjectTypes.Table, EntityStoreSchemaFilterEffect.Allow));
filters.Add(new EntityStoreSchemaFilterEntry(null, "dbo", "%", EntityStoreSchemaFilterObjectTypes.Function, EntityStoreSchemaFilterEffect.Exclude));

// generate the SSDL
string ssdlNamespace = modelName + "Model.Store";
EntityStoreSchemaGenerator essg = new EntityStoreSchemaGenerator(provider, connectionString, ssdlNamespace);
essg.GenerateForeignKeyProperties = includeForeignKeys;

IList<EdmSchemaError> ssdlErrors = essg.GenerateStoreMetadata(filters, version);
```

I only needed to explicitly exclude the functions.

Comment: Thanks to referenceSource, [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Entity.Design/System/Data/Entity/Design/SSDLGenerator/EntityStoreSchemaGeneratorDatabaseSchemaLoader.cs,204) is one of the locations filters are used to build the SQL query. Basically, if you have a "allow" on a FilterObjectType it will only include those explicitly matching. Thus you should have a "exclude" on any ObjectTypes you did not already filter with your "allow"s. Hope that makes sense. Thanks for this answer, led me to the information I needed.